# Rezising Linux Partition which contains the ubuntu OS in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, root, resize

I was trying to extend my `/` partition using ubuntu live cd after installation done before 6 months. For installing a software i needed 9GB more space in my root partition. The size of the root partition was 24gb only. To find a safe solution i used my virtual box OS, and after booting from ubuntu installation disk and extending the root partition using GParted worked like a charm. So I chosen to take the risk for my ubuntu 14.04 LTS version which is my host. After booting to a live ubuntu 14.04 cd I was able to delete an ntfs partition which was above my `/` partition for ubuntu. the resizing of my 24gb space to 61gb also didnt gave any error. But when i rebooted it ended up with a grub rescue menu. I tried to find a solution but nothing worked at all.

I did this one also:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount -o bind /dev/ /mnt/dev
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

`# Now within the chroot`

```
sudo update-grub
exit
```

`# Now outside chroot`

This also didnt helped. Pls help. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realize that partitions can be safely expanded only to the right side (i.e bottom part). Any attempt to resize it to the left firstly should have consumed a lot of time and secondly and inevitably destroy the grub. Instead of chrooting and installing the grub, i can suggest you a simpler method.

Live boot and open you /dev/sda7 partition in the file manager. Then, close it and open terminal and type the command.

```
sudo /media/ubuntu/disk-uuid/usr/sbin/grub-install /dev/sda --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu/disk-uuid/boot/
```

You don't need to do update-grub as your grub config files are already in the boot directory.

P.S- Note that you need to hit the *tab* key to get the uuid and then continue. I hope you know the right use of tab key before you proceed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545554/virtual-box-and-gnome-settings-doesnt-work